# Infinite loop error when trying to use mouseover function

Tags: jquery

This is driving me crazy for the last couple of days, and I can not figure it out. I am not that handy with JQuery.
I am using Sponsor Wall plugin:

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/

What i am trying to do is to create a function where on mouseenter will flip the image, and on mouseleave, the image will flip back to original state.

Right now I am getting an infinite loop error.

I trying few solutions posted here, but we no luck :-(

This is my code. If somebody can help out that will be great.

Thank you very much!!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

$('.sponsorFlip').bind("mouseover",function(){

    // $(this) point to the clicked .sponsorFlip element (caching it in elem for speed):

    var elem = $(this);

    // data('flipped') is a flag we set when we flip the element:

    if(elem.data('flipped'))
    {
        // If the element has already been flipped, use the revertFlip method
        // defined by the plug-in to revert to the default state automatically:

        elem.revertFlip();

        // Unsetting the flag:
        elem.data('flipped',false)
    }
    else
    {
        // Using the flip method defined by the plugin:

        elem.flip({
            direction:'tb',
            speed: 350,
            onBefore: function(){
                // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden from view with display:none)
                // into the clicked .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:

                elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
            }
        });

        // Setting the flag:
        elem.data('flipped',true);
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I apologize, I mis-read your previous code (I saw "mouseenter" when it is "mouseover")

Did you consider using 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' rather than mouseover? This will allow you to separate your logic (instead of having an if/else conditional) and handle the event appropriately?

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sponsorFlip').bind({
        /* FLIP ON ENTER */
        'mouseenter': function(e){
            var $el = $(this);
            $el.flip({  direction: 'lr', 
                speed: 350,
                onBefore: function() {
                $el.html($el.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
              }
            });
         },
         /* REVERT ON LEAVE */
         'mouseleave': function(){
              var $el = $(this);
              $el.revertFlip();
          }
      });           
  });
```

Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gX2WY/2/

(I removed the flip/revertFlip from JS fiddle to prevent an error - but the concept is there!)

Edit (easier to read than my comments)
Here's the link to the JS fiddle with changes I made: http://jsfiddle.net/VJsrj/
Here's a link to the zip with changes: http://www.box.com/s/v5ov3tl09xhr6gf1cj78

One thing to note - The Flip plugin has a few quirks with regards to the "revertFlip" method. Specifically, it's not a fan of being called when it's animating. I played around with some logic that would defer that method from being called (if you mouse-out while in animation), but ultimately decided to remove it (it caused a few other issues)

One thing I would suggest (maybe for the future) is considering CSS for your visuals and progressively "enhance" that experience for users browsing your site with supported browsers.

For instance:

http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/webkit-flip/demo/index.html

This page is functional in all modern browsers but is extra cool in webkit-based browsers (Chrome/Safari) - You could mimic a similar behavior by having a basic ":hover" and extending that for browsers that support it!

Good luck! Let me know if you have any additional questions :)

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: It was a question, but I apologize, I misread your previous code. I have updated my original question!

Comment: That looks perfect, but is there a assign an image and not text?

Comment: Yes, you can assign an image instead! 

I looked at your demo page (http://virtus.us.com/demo/demo.php) - Are you still interested in having the "flip" animation (using the plugin you provided in the original question?)

Comment: Yeah, i would love if I can have the flip animation. I have attached the link where you can download the folder if that might work: http://virtus.us.com/demo.zip

Comment: Hi there,

I looked at the link you provided and made a few changes. I posted these at jsfiddle as well uploaded the zip.


jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VJsrj/ (The demo kind of sucks here)

Comment: Sorry - previous comment was returned by mistake..
Hi there,

I looked at the link you provided and made a few changes. I posted those at jsfiddle as well as uploaded a zip with changes.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VJsrj/ (The demo kind of sucks here)
zip: http://www.box.com/s/v5ov3tl09xhr6gf1cj78

Comment: Jack, this is perfect!!!!! The only question I have, and it is not a big deal, if there is a way to remove the background color (gray) during flipping. Not to replace it with some other color, I will like to remove it completely, or maybe make it transparent?

Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind the mouseout event!

Comment: Not sure how to do that. I tried few options changing the code, but with no luck. Programming is new to me ... Can you maybe point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `.bind()` is incorrect.  Try this:

```
$('.sponsorFlip').bind(mouseover: function(){
    ...
```

However, if you're using jQuery 1.7 or above, it's recommended that you use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.bind()`.  Here's an example of `.on()`:

```
$('.sponsorFlip').on("mouseover",function(){
    ...
```

Also, you're missing a semicolon after `elem.data('flipped',false)` in the first half of the code.  It may not be strictly required, but pop it in there just in case.

Comment: It didn't work. I am using jQuery 1.7.2. When I added .on() it stopped working. Thanks

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `elem.data('flipped',false)`, could that help make it work?  Any chance you could set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate this?  Alternately, post your attempt with `.on()`?

Comment: It didnt change anything. This is the demo that i am working on:http://virtus.us.com/demo/demo.php

Comment: It works for me, though it flips as you move the mouse around.  It seems like it's detecting mouseover multiple times... maybe you need to set a flag when you enter and reset the flag on mouseout.  If the flag is set, have mouseover do nothing.